# Compute the quantity of some numbers that satisfy some condition

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have a sequence whose length is n and its contents are all digits, such as $b_nb_{n-1}...b_1(b_i=0,1,2,...,9)$. And $bn$ would not be $0$. Given L, R and m, if $L\le b_n*10^{n-1}+b_{n-1}*10^{n-2}+...+b1*10^0 \le R$ and $(b_n+b_{n-1}...+b_1) \mod m=0$, we would call this digit sequence is a good sequence. Are there any great algorithm that can compute the number of good sequences efficiently? n can be any integer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Example: $L=3463$, $R = 8576$, $m = 7$.

Split it into sub-problems as follows (all with $m=7$):

- $L = 3463$, $R = 3469$;
- $L = 3470$, $R = 3499$;
- $L = 3500$, $R = 3999$;
- $L = 4000$, $R = 7999$;
- $L = 8000$, $R = 8499$;
- $L = 8500$, $R = 8569$;
- $L = 8570$, $R = 8576$.

Each of these sub-problems now has a simpler form. The top few digits are fixed, then one digit has some upper and lower bound, and then the remaining digits are unconstrained. In particular, this means the bounds on the digits are now all independent. We can make an algorithm for this restricted case.

Let $C_{k,r}$ count the number of $k$-digit numbers whose digits sum to $r$ modulo $m$. Let $\vec C_k$ be the vector $(C_{k,0}, \dots, C_{k, m-1})^T$. Then we have the following recurrence relation:

$$\vec C_0 = (1, 0, \dots, 0)^T$$
$$\vec C_{k+1} = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \vec C_k$$

I hope it is obvious how I constructed this matrix, which is for $m=7$, and also how you would go about constructing it for other $m$. Note that every column sums to $10$, being the number of possible digits.

I this way we can easily and efficiently compute all the $C_{k,r}$. We can then use that information to solve the sub-problems above. For example, for the sub-problem $L = 8000$, $R = 8499$, we need to compute $\vec C_2$, and then sum the elements from $r = 2 \equiv -(8+4)$ to $r = 6 \equiv -(8+0)$.

I hope you can see how to generalise from this partial example solution to a general algorithm, because I think that an attempt to explain the algorithm in general would be much harder to understand!